# MS Access 2007, checking current user against a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

We have a simple access database, and would like a button on a form to only be available to select members of staff. (The button has an event tied to it). I'd like to store the usernames of the staff allowed to click the button in a separate table.

What I'd like to do, is perform a simple query to see if the username exists in the table, and set the enabled state of the button depending upon the outcome.

My background is C# and SQL Server, but VBA and access are new to me, and I think I'm struggling with the quirks of this environment.

I've got the username of the logged on user in a string `fOSUserName` via a call to GetUserNameA in advapi32.dll, but I'm struggling with the simplest of queries to determine if the username exists in the table.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset    
Set db = CurrentDb    
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [USERS] WHERE [USERS].[NAME] = '" & _
    fOSUsername & "'"        
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
If Not rs.EOF Then
    intResult = rs.Fields(0)
Else
    intResult = 0
End If
rs.Close
db.Close
```

This fails on `db.OpenRecordset` giving me the error

> Run-time error '3061':
>
> Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Can anyone offer some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your [USERS] object **is not** a table but Query (with parameter). Also, if you had a syntax error like '&_'(invalid) as opposed to '& _'(valid), your database would not compile. So, if table vs query is your case, please use the following:

```
...
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Users")
qdf.Parameters("UserNameParameter") = fOSUsername
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
...
```

Comment: Sorry, `&_` / `& _` is a mistake on my part. I split the line to improve formatting on SO and messed up. Now fixed.

Comment: @Bryan - also, check the fOSUsername value. For example, if you get SQL as the following you could get run-time error as well: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable WHERE NewColumn = [username]. Because [username] would be considered as parameter

Comment: I think that is the problem I'm seeing (note the text of my runtime error in my question, it refers to parameters). I've seen a few posts on various sites mentioning parameters, but to be honest, didn't understand how it worked, and didn't have much success with the examples I've seen. To be honest, I could have written a basic C# desktop app that interfaces to an SQL Express instance in the time I've spent on this now, I'm beginning to think this is probably the best way forward for me now.

Comment: Bryan, I am sorry it takes so much time to resolve. I would suggest couple options in order to narrow down the problem. 1) get rid of the variable from the SQL string. Just try plain string with hard-coded username. 2) check the value of fOSUsername and use it (hard-coded again) in SQL string. 3) Copy your SQL and create query in Query builder and run. One of these would answer your question, I am sure

Comment: Igor, no need to apologise. My comment wasn't inteded to sound negative to your answer in any way, apologies if it came across that way! I'm so used to working with c# that I find access/vba to be hard work. I guess what I'm trying to say is that I'm at the point where I'm giving up and going to write a desktop app, as I fear I'm going to hit many more obstacles like this along the way. I hoped access might have given me fast results, but my inexperience with it seems to negate that chance. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

When you continue a line in VBA, you need a space between before the line continuation character ("_").  So instead of this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [USERS] WHERE [USERS].[NAME] = '" &_
    fOSUsername & "'"
```

Use this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [USERS] WHERE [USERS].[NAME] = '" & _
    fOSUsername & "'"
```

However, as @Igor Turman pointed out, the lack of a space before the underline character should trigger a compile error.  So I'm unsure what's going on but suggest you fix it anyway to avoid confusion.

I'll suggest that rather than opening a recordset, and then reading a value from that recordset, this could be handled simply with the DCount() function.

```
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[USERS].[NAME] = '" & fOSUsername & "'"
Debug.Print "strCriteria: '" & strCriteria & "'"
If DCount("*", "USERS", strCriteria) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "not found"
Else
    Debug.Print "found"
End IF
```

If your missing parameter error is because USERS is a query rather than a table, you can ask DCount() to use a table instead.  Or fix the query.

Comment: 1) &_ vs & _ would throw a _syntax_ error not run-time. But you are right, it should be **& _** 2) if strSQL was an empty string the error would be "...cannot find the input table/query ''..."

Comment: @Igor Turman  You're right. I still want to direct his attention to DCount() for this.

Comment: As posted as a comment to Igor's answer, `&_` / `& _` was a typo. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally familiar with the way you are using it, but I've always done it this way:

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[your access db file path and name];Persist Security Info=False"

sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [USERS] WHERE [USERS].[NAME] = '" &_ 
    fOSUsername & "'" 

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sSQL, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then 
    intResult = rs.Fields(0) 
Else 
    intResult = 0 


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, but as the code is in the database, how would I specify the datasource as itself?

Comment: @Bryan If you want to use ADO for this, instead of setting cn to `New ADODB.Connection`, use `Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection`

Comment: AS @HansUp said - you can just use CurrentProject.Connection, and it will give you the current DB...